# Decimal places - jQuery

Tags: jquery, decimal-point

To place decimal plases in a text box I have use jquery.number plugin.

```
 $("#" + crisisCapId).number(true, 2);
```

After adding this plugin, if someone enter 0 i want to clear text box (" ").

```
 if (crisisCapValue == 0) {
      $("#" + crisisCapId).val(' ');
    }
```

But it is not working. How can we remove this plugin.

Full Code

```
 $("#" + crisisCapId).blur(function () {
        var crisisCapValue = $("#" + crisisCapId).val();

        if (crisisCapValue > 0) {
            $("#" + crisisCapId).number(true, 2);


        } else {

            $("#" + crisisCapId).val('');
        }

    });
```

Comment: We need more context. If you console.log  $("#" + crisisCapId).number(true, 2); what value you have? Also, what is the value of crisisCapValue before you check it?

Comment: Initialy it can be any value. as a example if I enter 5, it will automaticaly set as 5.00 using  jquery.number plugin . But if I enter 0, I want to clear the textbox. clear means I want to empty the textbox.

Comment: Can you update your question with the full code. Where is `crisisCapValue` defined? You may just be able to use an `if{}else{}` cant see what you are trying until I see the code. Also why do you want to 'remove this plugin' it appears to be doing what its being told to.

Comment: full code updated. Actualy i want to clear the textbox without any value. I thought removing pluging is tha method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because `$("#" + crisisCapId).val()` is a string, and therefore can't be evaluated against a number. You need to parse the input value as a number before your conditional:

```
$('#' + crisisCapId).blur(function () {

    var $this = $(this),
        crisisCapValue = parseFloat($this).val());

    if (crisisCapValue > 0) {
        $this.val(crisisCapValue.toFixed(2));
    } else {
        $this.val('');
    }

});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jwmfuLLr/1/

Comment: Thank you very much Denisol. This is what I wanted. It is working properly. You save my job. :D

Comment: No worries, here to help :)